# Jquery scrolling text like marquee

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, marquee

I am using jquery marquee plugins [jQuery.Marquee](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee) and [jquery.simplemarquee](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/jquery.simplemarquee) .

[jquery.simplemarquee](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/jquery.simplemarquee) not working with jQuery 1.7.2 on opera.
Now i am trying to do similar like [jquery.simplemarquee](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/jquery.simplemarquee) using [jQuery.Marquee](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee) plugin. I mean if text scroll ended and after when it start i want to add pause / start option like [jquery.simplemarquee](http://bit.ly/1VODolp) .

**Example :**

Need like [jquery.simplemarquee](http://bit.ly/1VODolp) .

> [jQuery.Marquee](http://bit.ly/1GEAcwp)

Comment: Its unclear what your asking ...  One solution is to not use a marquee at all.

Comment: [What are arguments against the usage of a ticker / marquee on websites?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76951/what-are-arguments-against-the-usage-of-a-ticker-marquee-on-websites)

Comment: I updated question @AlexK.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Simple to add in code with examples.

http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/
http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/index.html